# Does the Google Maps API provide a way to get all the space / apt numbers at a given address?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I need to get a list of all space numbers in a mobile home park so I can do a reverse lookup on the addresses and I don't want to go one by one because I have no idea how many I'll be doing. Can I get this info easily with Google's Map API? So far my idea is to use Google Maps for the address then use White Pages for the reverse lookup.

Comment: There is no such functionality in Google Maps APIs.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Any other solution that you know of?